# For a foreign language PCT application in US national phase, is it necessary to hire an officially certified translator?

Tags: pct, translation

I have a PCT application that recently entered national phase, and I am now seeking its registration in the United States. This application was originally filed in Spanish, therefore I'm going to have to translate it to English. Since I consider myself decently proficient at English and capable of communicating my invention in that language, I'd like to translate it myself. I'm not sure about the United States, but in Mexico I am not legally allowed to do it myself, as translations here may only be done by a highly select VIP club of officially certified translators that charge exorbitant rates.

Is it possible to supply my own English translation of the priority document to the USPTO, without having to hire an officially certified translator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it yourself.  The U.S. does not have any rules about who can do the translation. If you use a U.S. registered practitioner to help they might suggest they do some English to patent English translation.